# Word and line highlighting add up to unreadable in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I highlight a line in Visual Studio, some words are highlighted such that they are difficult to read. The picture below shows the same line unhighlighted line and highlighted (two examples).

[image: comparison of line highlighing]

I've been looking through the zillion options in VS but can't figure out a way to clean this up.

The screen shot is from VS2012 and I do have Resharper installed (but I do recall something similar in VS2010 as well. Thanks, this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to edit any existing theme in VS2012 and modify every aspect of it through Tools->Options->Environment (highlighting as well).
However...I had the similar problem and ended up using the third-party theme for the editor, and built one for the surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to download one of the numerous themes present at [studiostyl.es](http://studiostyl.es/) and then disable the Resharper Highlight Current Line option (**Resharper -> Options -> Editor -> HighLight Current Line checkbox**)

In this way the standard option in the **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> CurrentLine** takes precedence. This command, set every word of the current line to the foreground and background color choosen without trying to color each category word with its color.

Answer (score 1):

While the suggested third party tools may have done the trick, I did find a "reset to defaults" button which fix the highlighting problem. I may however try some of the suggested tools anyway to maybe tailor the look some more. (which is probably what caused the problem in the first place).